# How to push entire React folder to github?

Tags: reactjs, github, push

I am working on a project that uses both React and Springboot apps, so I have individual folders for each of those and am trying to get them both into my github repo.  I was easily able to drag and drop the springboot folder, but my react one does not upload at all when I drag it into the upload box.  Is there an easy terminal command in vs code (the editor I'm using) to add the entire folder?

Comment: Define "not cooperating". Github has plenty of documentation on how to set up repos, add files to the local copy, commit changes, and then push the updated files to the online repo. Did you read those at all?

Comment: make sure you have deleted the node_modules folder before drag and dropping it

Comment: @COMRADEDEV is that not a crucial folder for running the app? Sorry, I should have said, this is the first time I've had to use both frameworks

Comment: Your `package.json` file has all list of all the modules you have installed for that project, and `node_modules` stores all those modules, if you are uploading your source code somewhere, you don't need to put the `node_modules` folder because, anyone using that code can just download your code, and inside the code folder, he can simply run the command `npm install` which will download and install all those modules once again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to add your 2 different projects in 1 repository, you can firstly put both of your project folder inside 1 main folder, example:

```
MyFolder:
  - MyReactProject
  - MySpringbootProject
```

here `MyFolder` is your main folder, which has both of your projects, react and springboot.
then finally make a file inside `MyFolder` with name `.gitignore`, and put this line inside that file:

```
**/node_modules
```

what this file will do, is when you will push your code to github, it will ignore all the files and folders which are listed inside `.gitignore` file.

---

## You Don't Need `node_modules` folder

when uploading your code somewhere online, you don't need to upload the `node_modules` folder, because this folder contains all the dependencies your project need, but when uploading your code online people can download those dependencies by calling the command `npm install` which will read all the modules needed from your `package.json` file, and download it on your machine.

---

To upload your code online you first have to authorize yourself on your local git program, to authorize yourself for github you can read this [Article](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/caching-your-github-credentials-in-git).

After authorizing yourself, firstly make a new empty github repository, by going to github or just by clicking this [Link](https://github.com/new), after making a github repository open Terminal/Command Prompt in your Folder where both of your projects were, in this context my both projects were in `MyFolder`.

After opening Terminal/Command Prompt enter this commands:

```
git init
git branch -M main
git add .
git commit "Added all the files"
```

After running these commands, finally run these 2 final commands:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/repository-name.git
```

here, replace `username` with your github username, and replace `repository-name` with the name of your repository you specified while make a new repository.

and finally run this command

```
git push -u origin main
```

and your code should be pushed on github.

---

If you don't want to use git commands you can also use, [Github Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/), but it is recommended you first learn basics of git and then use github desktop